# Gitlab runner waits a lot after "Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing"

Tags: ios, xcode, gitlab-ci

What may be the reason of this:

[image]

[image]

It waits for more than 30 minutes there and then moves on. Why it takes so much time after `Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing.`?

Here is how my lane for testing is defined:

```
lane :test do
    scan(scheme: SCHEME_NAME, code_coverage: true, clean: true, output_directory: OUTPUT_PATH + 'tests', devices: ["iPhone 8 Plus"], reset_simulator: true, disable_concurrent_testing: true)
end
```

Comment: Not a solution, but maybe a lead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326847/xcodebuild-skip-finished-requesting-crash-reports-continuing-with-testing check the `scanfile`? There might be actions that don't output logs (like cleans, etc.)

Comment: I have added another parameter `disable_concurrent_testing: true` to my `scan` function inside my Fastfile, where I defined my lane. It doesnt work, still the same.